# How to Read XML as Objects and Write to MySQL using Haskell

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt, hdbc

I have several XML files of the following format in path location:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVPWH.jpg)

```
<Group>
  <Group_No>1</Group_No>
  <Group_Name>One</Group_Name>
  <Member_List>
    <Member>
      <Member_No>1</Member_No>
      <Member_Name>Mike</Member_Name>
    </Member>
    <Member>
      <Member_No>2</Member_No>
      <Member_Name>Jacob</Member_Name>
    </Member>
  </Member_List>
</Group>
```

I want to read all those XML files and create Group and Member data objects and save them to a MySQL DB using Haskell(I know I need to use HXT and HDBC libraries but I am confused as to how I could use them). Though there are examples for reading XML, they do not show how to traverse through the objects to save to DB.

DB structure:

```
DB name : L group_member_db

Group table:

Group ID:PK , Int, AutoIncrement

Group No: String

Group Name:String

Member Table:

Member ID:PK, Int, AutoIncrement

Member No:String

Member Name:String
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently your question is too broad. Can you break it down to an individual problem you're having? There are several Haskell libraries for reading XML files. Have you created your own data types `Group` and `Member`? What do they look like? Break down your problem into smaller pieces: 1) how do I read files? 2) How do I turn the XML into some record? 3) How do I save a record to my database?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and breaking my problem into smaller pieces. But I do not want to post them as three separate questions because I am unable to combine different solutions. However I have datatypes as :        data Group = Group {GroupNo, GroupName :: String} and data Member = Member {MemberNo, MemberName :: String}

Comment: Hey @harshainfo, it would be easier to help you if we had the actual XML file, not an image of it. Could you post that?

Comment: XML file added as a code block for easy copying.